# How to use rules_webtesting?

Tags: webdriver, bazel, bazel-rules

I want to use https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_webtesting. I am using Bazel 5.2.0.

The whole project can be found [here](https://github.com/Vertexwahn/BazelDemos/tree/master/WebdriverDemo).

My `WORKSPACE.bazel` file looks like this:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "io_bazel_rules_webtesting",
    sha256 = "3ef3bb22852546693c94e9b0b02c2570e74abab6f800fd58e0cbe79492e49c1b",
    urls = [
        "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_webtesting/archive/581b1557e382f93419da6a03b91a45c2ac9a9ec8/rules_webtesting.tar.gz",
    ],
)

load("@io_bazel_rules_webtesting//web:repositories.bzl", "web_test_repositories")

web_test_repositories()
```

My `BUILD.bazel` file looks like this:

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_webtesting//web:py.bzl", "py_web_test_suite")

py_web_test_suite(
    name = "browser_test",
    srcs = ["browser_test.py"],
    browsers = [
        "@io_bazel_rules_webtesting//browsers:chromium-local",
    ],
    local = True,
    deps = ["@io_bazel_rules_webtesting//testing/web"],
)
```

`browser_test.py` looks like this:

```
import unittest
from testing.web import webtest


class BrowserTest(unittest.TestCase):
  def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webtest.new_webdriver_session()

  def tearDown(self):
    try:
      self.driver.quit()
    finally:
      self.driver = None

  # Your tests here

if __name__ == "__main__":
  unittest.main()
```

When I try to do a `bazel build //...` I get (under Ubuntu 20.04 and macOS):

```
INFO: Invocation ID: 74c03efd-9caa-4174-9fda-42f7ff37e38b
ERROR: error loading package '': Every .bzl file must have a corresponding package, but '@io_bazel_rules_webtesting//web:repositories.bzl' does not have one. Please create a BUILD file in the same or any parent directory. Note that this BUILD file does not need to do anything except exist.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.038s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
```

The error message does not make sense to me, since there is a BUILD file in
https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_webtesting/blob/581b1557e382f93419da6a03b91a45c2ac9a9ec8/BUILD.bazel
and https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_webtesting/blob/581b1557e382f93419da6a03b91a45c2ac9a9ec8/web/BUILD.bazel.

I also tried a different version of Bazel - but with the same result.

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a `strip_prefix = "rules_webtesting-581b1557e382f93419da6a03b91a45c2ac9a9ec8"` in your `http_archive` call.

For debugging, you can look in the folder where Bazel extracts it: `bazel-out/../../../external/io_bazel_rules_webtesting`. `@io_bazel_rules_webtesting//web` translates to `bazel-out/../../../external/io_bazel_rules_webtesting/web`, so if that folder doesn't exist things won't work.